# SwiftUI Firebase: Sending a message to the mail

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, firebase-authentication

In the function I want to add sending a message to the confirmation email, if you confirm, then you get to `Homescreen()`, else `SignUp()`.
What do I need to add to my code?

```
    func register(){
        
        if self.email != ""{
            if self.pass == self.repass{  
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.email, password: self.pass) { (res, err) in
                    
                    if err != nil{   
                        self.error = err!.localizedDescription
                        self.alert.toggle()
                        return
                    }
                    
                    print("success")
                    
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil)
                }
            }
            else{   
                self.error = "Password mismatch"
                self.alert.toggle()
            }
        }
        else{  
            self.error = "Please fill all the contents properly"
            self.alert.toggle()
        }
    }
```

`SignUp()` - View where registration takes place
`Homescreen()` - View where the message about successful registration appears

Comment: Can you elaborate what "sending a message to the confirmation email" means? What do *you* expect to do, and what changes for the user?

Comment: When the user clicks register, he receives an email with account confirmation from firebase and after confirming the account, a view - Homescreen() appears in the application, otherwise it appears SignUp()

Comment: Are you look for howto [send a verification email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email)?

Comment: Exactly, but how can I combine it with my existing code?

Comment: There is literally a step by step documentation for this. You could at least try to implement it and come back as problems arise. We ain´t gone write the code for you.

Comment: Dude... I'll figure out the documentation, I thought my question would speed up the process

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to sign the user in with email using following code:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, link: self.link) { authResult, error in
      // ...
    }
```

- If there is an error, present the error alert to the user.
- If sign in was successful, you can use the following code to get the current user:

```
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {

}
```

And inside of the curly brackets just check if current user has already verified the E-Mail with `user.isEmailVerified`

- If that is the case, then simply present your Homescreen
- If current user has not verified his E-Mail yet, you can present an alert, where the user can choose if he wants to have the verification E-Mail sent out again. If that is the case, you can simply resend the E-Mail with

```
user.sendEmailVerification {error in
   
}
```

and the user will get his verification E-Mail or there can occur an error while sending the Email so you should handle that error aswell!

Good luck!

---

You can also check the [Firebase docs for Email Verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email)